# Add values from API call to dropdown Angular

Tags: angular, api, angular8

I'm facing a problem while I want to display some values which I got from a API call in a dropdown in the fronted.

I call my endpoint like this:

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  const values = this.backendService.getAllValues().subscribe()
}
```

The call works, I get the following output:

```
0: {name: "Data Visualisation",…}
 name: "Data Visualisation"
1: {name: "Watchning TV",…}
 name: "Watchning TV"
```

Now, I d'like to display those values in my dropdowon:

**component.html**

```
<scs-dropdown>
   <scs-dropdown-item *ngFor="let value of values" [value]="value.name">
   </scs-dropdown-item>
</scs-dropdown>
```

But nothing is displayed in the dropdown, what do I wrong?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for the same

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you should set the values attribute. It should be like this:

```
values = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.backendService.getAllValues().subscribe(response => {
        this.values = [];
        for (const item in response) {
            this.values.push(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Look that values is a class attribute, not a variable defined in ngOnInit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I got this error message: `Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?ts(2322)`

Comment: This is because your response is not an array. You should convert to an array before assign to this.values

Comment: where should I define the `item`?

Comment: With this solution I got the error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`

Comment: Can you tell me what shows when you add console.log(response) at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The Values you get from the API Must be mapped into an Array using the ' .map => ' operator then once mapped you can loop through the values on the interface

Comment: I think that your answer is wrong. The return type of the api call is an array.. This return type is an Subscription:    this.backendService.getAllValues().subscribe()

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and show us the console output:

```
values = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.backendService.getAllValues().subscribe( arr => {
      console.info(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
      values = arr
  });
}


<scs-dropdown>
   <scs-dropdown-item *ngFor="let value of values" [value]="value.name">
      {{value.label}} :-)
   </scs-dropdown-item>
</scs-dropdown>
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

Don't forget to [unsubscribe](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I got this error message: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?ts(2322)